# Replace tags in DOM

Tags: php, dom

I try to replace links in a HTML string to a text but because I replace the source inside the iteration I get weird mixed results. Any idea how to solve this:

```
$body='<a href="link1">text1</a> and <a href="link2">text2</a> and <a href="link3">text3</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($body);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $link = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $text = $anchor->nodeValue;
    $new = $dom->createTextNode($text."\n".$link."\n");
    $anchor->parentNode->replaceChild($new,$anchor);
    echo($text); //debug
}
$body_plain = $dom->saveHTML();
```

It has to become:

```
text1
link1
and
text2
link2
and
text3
link3
```

But instead the second link will not be replaced. When debugging it skips the second link:

```
text1
link1 and <a href="link2">text2</a> and
text3
link3
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What second link? Could you also add the HTML markup you're trying to process and the expected output?

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`, and loop through the nodes _backwards_ (from n-1 to 0) – this will avoid problems with nodes being removed from the collection during the loop.

Comment: @CBroe no that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` produces a *live* list of nodes. After replacing the first link with its text, the code then looks for the second link *in the resulting DOM*, which is the third link in the original.

Personally, I prefer to use XPath even for simple things:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$anchors = $xpath->query("//a");
```

This will work ;)

Comment: Thanks, never heard of "live" vars since I thought I put the result set into a "static" `$anchors`. There are many accepted and + voted answers on stackoverflow with "my code", which are all not working I think.